# Can I capture JSON data already being sent with a userscript/Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, userscripts

I'm trying to write a userscript/Chrome extension to capture JSON data being sent while using a web service so that I can reformat it and display selected portion on page. Currently the JSON is sent as the application loads (as I've observed from watching traffic with Fiddler 2). Is my only option to request the JSON again or is capture possible? As I'm not providing a code example, a requested answer is even some guidance on what method / topic to research or if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Are you doing this for one specific site or you want it to work on all sites?

Comment: A specific site so the URL / JSON naming / etc are all static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No easy way.

If it is for a specific site you might look into intercepting and overwriting part of a code which sends a request. For example if it is sent on a button click you can replace existing click handler with your own implementation.

You can also try to make a proxy for `XMLHttpRequest`. Not sure if this even possible, never seen a working example. You can look at some attempts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809342/how-can-i-create-a-xmlhttprequest-wrapper-proxy).

For all these tasks you probably would need to run your javascript code out of sandboxed content script to be able to access parent page variables, so you would need to inject `<script>` tag with your code right into the page from a content script: