# How interceptor works in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to java script and angularjs. As per angular documents and other references I understood that with the help of interceptor we can handle adding auth header to every http calls etc. But how can I restrict interceptor to add header only for specific http calls?. How can i use interceptor to intercept only specific http calls? how can I customize interceptor?

Comment: take a look at what they did here : https://github.com/cloudspace/angular_devise

Comment: You intercept all calls, whether your interceptor acts on them is what you need to decide. Look at interceptor API, what parameters are available for you to filter what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a XMLHttpRequest wrapper/proxy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809342/how-can-i-create-a-xmlhttprequest-wrapper-proxy)