# Create an object proxy which behaves like the object as much possible as it can

Tags: javascript, proxy

I need to hijack XHR on a page, I start from proxy the XHR object, first proxy `new` operator:

```
class ClassHandler {
  constructor(proxy) {
    this.proxy = proxy;
  }

  construct(target, args) {
    const obj = new target(...args);
    return new Proxy(obj, new this.proxy(obj));
  }
}

(function(XMLHttpRequest) {
  unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest = new Proxy(
    XMLHttpRequest,
    new ClassHandler(XhrHandler)
  );
})(XMLHttpRequest);
```

Then `XhrProxy` needs to proxy everything to real XHR object, I found this is very complicated, so separate it into several components.

#### Basic properties

```
const ProxyGetTarget = Symbol('ProxyGetTarget');
const ProxyGetHandler = Symbol('ProxyGetHandler');
class ObjectHandler {
  constructor(target) {
    this.target = target;
  }

  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    if (target.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
    } else if (prop == ProxyGetTarget) {
      return target;
    } else if (prop == ProxyGetHandler) {
      return this;
    } else {
      const value = target[prop];
      if (typeof value == 'function')
        return new Proxy(value, new FunctionHandler(value));
      return value;
    }
  }

  set(target, prop, value) {
    return Reflect.set(target, prop, value);
  }
}
```

I injected a property `ProxyGetTarget` which returns the real target for future use. Next I'll explain why proxy functions with `FunctionHandler` in the object.

#### Member function calls

This is a bit tricky, when calling a function on the object:

```
xhr.open()
```

`xhr` is our proxy object, not the real native XHR object, the open function will be called with `this` set to the proxy object, In order to forward open call to real xhr object, we need proxy all functions returned by `get`:

```
class FunctionHandlerBase extends ObjectHandler {
  apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    const realTarget = thisArg[ProxyGetTarget];
    if (!realTarget) throw new Error('illegal invocations');
    return this.call(this.target, thisArg, realTarget, argumentsList);
  }
}

class FunctionHandler extends FunctionHandlerBase {
  call(fn, proxy, target, argumentsList) {
    fn.apply(target, argumentsList);
  }
}
```

With this setup, I can inject any code into any member function using following method:

```
class XhrHandler extends ObjectHandler{
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    if (prop === 'open') {
      return new Proxy(target.open, new this.open(target.open));
    } else {
      return super.get(target, prop, receiver);
    }
  }
}

XhrHandler.prototype.open = class extends FunctionHandlerBase {
  call(fn, proxy, realTarget, argumentsList) {
    // Do whatever before real xhr.open call
    // ...
    // ...

    // Call real xhr.open
    return fn.apply(realTarget, argumentsList);
  }
};
```

#### Event listeners

As event listeners will expose real object as `this` argument in the callback function, I don't want anyone get my secret real target, I should also wrap it with the proxy.

```
class EventTargetHandler extends ObjectHandler {
  constructor(target) {
    super(target);
    this.listeners = {};
  }

  getListeners(type) {
    if (!this.listeners.hasOwnProperty(type))
      this.listeners[type] = new Map();
    return this.listeners[type];
  }

  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    if (prop === 'addEventListener') {
      return new Proxy(
        target.addEventListener,
        new this.addEventListener(target.addEventListener, this)
      );
    } else if (prop === 'removeEventListener') {
      return new Proxy(
        target.removeEventListener,
        new this.removeEventListener(target.removeEventListener, this)
      );
    } else return super.get(target, prop, receiver);
  }
}

EventTargetHandler.prototype.addEventListener = class extends FunctionHandlerBase {
  call(fn, proxy, realTarget, argumentsList) {
    const type = argumentsList[0];
    const listener = argumentsList[1];
    const bridge = listener.bind(proxy);
    argumentsList[1] = bridge;
    proxy[ProxyGetHandler].getListeners(type).set(listener, bridge);
    return fn.apply(realTarget, argumentsList);
  }
};

EventTargetHandler.prototype.removeEventListener = class extends FunctionHandlerBase {
  call(fn, proxy, realTarget, argumentsList) {
    const type = argumentsList[0];
    const listener = argumentsList[1];
    const cache = proxy[ProxyGetHandler].getListeners(type);
    if (cache.has(listener)) {
      argumentsList[1] = cache.get(listener);
      cache.delete(listener);
    }
    return fn.apply(realTarget, argumentsList);
  }
};
```

#### Event handlers

Not done yet ... I need to wrap all `set` to the event handler properties.

## Problems

Hmm, hijack XHR ? easy task, let's do it in 5 minutes.

...

...

...

After 5 hours, I'm still struggling with those proxies.

Maybe I misunderstand the propose of the design of `Proxy` API, I found it very complicated to wrap an object, almost impossible.

I just want my Proxy behaves as same as the origin object, **is there any easier approach ?**

Comment: What is the higher level objective of the hijacking? Seems over complicated creating a proxy for each method

Comment: @charlietfl My goal is easy, just make my proxy behave as same as the target. Sometimes return a this bounded function may work, but what if used like this `xhr1.open.apply(xhr2, ['GET', 'https://example.com/'])`

Comment: OK. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53401323/1175966 and from that explain what additional functionality would be needed. Trying to understand what your higher level objective is

Comment: @charlietfl Without use of proxy, it can be easily detected by page, `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` should be a native function, but has been replaced by an js function.

Comment: What does *"it can be easily detected by page"* mean? You still haven't explained higher level objective

Comment: a) Yes, proxying native (exotic) objects is complicated b) I'd suggest to do it less generic, do not use dynamically created `class` instances for your handlers but simply plain objects. Start simply, add abstractions later when you feel you need them.

Comment: @Bergi I also realized that native functions are causing problems, unlike pure js function, the native function doesn't accept proxy object as this. But the event handler/listener problem doesn't related to native functions. Real `this` is exposed to the constructor of the object, if the object stores real `this` somewhere then pass it outside via event handler/listener may cause problems.

Comment: Yes, that's another reason to keep the wrapper as thin as possible. But you still haven't told us *why* you "*need to hijack XHR on a page*" and what you want to do with the highjacked objects.

Comment: @Bergi write an UserScript using tampermonkey. I want to make it as stable as I can, so the hijacked object should behave as same as original object.